# How java works with classes internally?

Tags: java, jar

At first i'll describe envir:

I have jar-archive with

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;
public interface A {};

-------------------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.test;
public class B {
    private A a;
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    } 
};
```

I also have current app with

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;
public interface A {};
-------------------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.test;
public class AImpl implements A {}
-------------------------------------------
package com.stackoverflow.test;
class TestInvocation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        /* Instance of class B gained via external lib */
        Object obj;
        A a = new AImpl();
        try {
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("setA", A.class);
            method.invoke(obj, a);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When i'm invoking setA from jar B (which accepts jar com.stackoverflow.test.A) and pushing as a parameter com.stackoverflow.test.A from app i gain NoSuchMethodException. When i'm changing jar B method definition to accept Object as argument and trying to cast AImpl to jar A it says ClassCastException.

My question: Does A from jar differs from app A? If yes - what can i do in this case?

My target - DI using external jars.

If it helps - lib that i used to load class from jar is here https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. wrap interface in external jar
2. use this jar as a lib for both B and main app

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same after changing the type invocation as below?

Object obj

B obj

Since the reflection is referring to Object.class since the datatype of the obj variable was of type Object, it will get a NoSuchMethodException.

The solution should be to change the datatype to B of the Obj variable and check.

Comment: B is a part of jar. It's inaccessible in main app.